# Transform a lattice polygon to minimum diameter by shearing

Tags: code-golf, math, grid, geometry

Given is a grid polygon by the list of its integer vertex coordinates arranged along the perimeter, in the form

\$(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), \cdots , (x_n,y_n)\$ with \$n \ge 3\$.

The polygon is completed by connecting point \$n\$ to point \$1\$.

For simplicity, it may be assumed that the polygon is simple and does not have interior angles \$\gt \pi\$.

The **diameter D** is defined here as the largest Euclidean distance between any two points on the circumference of the polygon.

A polygon can be deformed by **applying shear** while the area remains the same. The area \$A\$ of a polygon can be calculated in a known way, but it is not needed for the task at hand, because the area will not be changed by any shear.

See Wikipedia [Shear Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping).

### Challenge

**Your task is to create a function that, given a polygon, finds an arbitrary sequence of such shears so that the diameter d of the transformed polygon becomes as small as possible.**

This is related to a [question in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433773/upper-bound-on-the-diameter-of-a-convex-lattice-n-gon-with-a-given-area) and [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253633/the-smallest-area-of-a-convex-grid-polygon).

Only those shears should be considered that are parallel to the coordinate axes and that result in a polygon with integer coordinates, i.e., with integer, but potentially negative, \$m\$ in the transformation matrices

\$
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & m \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
\hspace {3mm}or \hspace {3mm}
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
m & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
\$

The program shall return the value of the minimum possible squared diameter \$d^2\$ and the transformed vertex coordinates, such that \$min(x'_i) = min(y'_i) = 0\$.

The coordinates can be passed to the function in whatever form seems most appropriate, e.g., as a matrix or as vectors or as a reference to a data structure. It is permissible to overwrite the input coordinates in the result.

If it is possible in the selected language with little effort, then a framework program should be made available that reads and outputs the results in the following format:

\$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\cdots,(x_n,y_n)\$

The commas between \$x\$ and \$y\$ and between \$),(\$ are mandatory. The calculated squared diameter shall also be output.

A framework program must not perform any pre- or post-processing other than reading and displaying the data and conversion to/from the required form for the transformation function.

The program should be able to handle polygons with at least 40 vertices.

This is Code Golf, i.e., the shortest code (in bytes) able to solve the problem wins. **However, only the length of the transformation function is used for the Code Golf score.**

The described form of output is chosen in order to be able to be used as input for a visualization program, e.g., Markus Sigg's [PolygonalAreasViewer](http://antiton.de/PolygonalAreas/index.html?(1,4),(2,2),(3,1),(4,1),(6,2),(7,3),(9,6),(10,8),(10,9),(9,10),(8,10),(5,9),(3,8),(2,7),(1,5))

### Example

```
Input, a polygon with n=15 and D^2=2810:
(1,1),(3,2),(6,4),(16,11),(23,16),(34,24),(38,27),(43,31),(44,32),(42,31),(39,29),(32,24),(21,16),(6,5),(2,2)
First shear x' = x - y
d^2=1105: (0,1),(1,2),(2,4),( 5,11),( 7,16),(10,24),(11,27),(12,31),(12,32),(11,31),(10,29),( 8,24),( 5,16),(1,5),(0,2)
Second shear y' = y - 2*x'
d^2=193: (0,1),(1,0),(2,0),( 5, 1),( 7, 2),(10, 4),(11, 5),(12, 7),(12, 8),(11, 9),(10, 9),( 8, 8),( 5, 6),(1,3),(0,2)
Third shear: x'' = x' - y'
d^2=82: (-1,1),(1,0),(2,0),( 4, 1),( 5, 2),( 6, 4),( 6, 5),( 5, 7),( 4, 8),( 2, 9),( 1, 9),( 0, 8),(-1, 6),(-2,3),(-2,2)
No further reduction of diameter possible; normalize position x''' = x'' + 2, y''' = y'
Expected return value: 82 (=d^2) and coordinates printed: 
 (1,1),(3,0),(4,0),(6,1),(7,2),(8,4),(8,5),(7,7),(6,8),(4,9),(3,9),(2,8),(1,6),(0,3),(0,2)
```

[image: Applied shears]

### Test Cases

```
n = 3
A=1/2, D^2=26: (0,0),(1,0),(5,1)
->     d^2= 2: (0,0),(1,0),(1,1)

A=1/2, D^2=74: (0,0),(3,2),(7,5)
->     d^2= 2: (0,0),(1,0),(1,1)

A=50, D^2=233: (-3,2),( 3,-2),(10,10)
->    d^2=169: ( 0,4),(10, 0),( 5,12) 

n = 7
A=6.5, D^2=13: (1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(3,2),(1,3),(0,3),(0,2)
->     d^2=13: (1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(3,2),(1,3),(0,3),(0,2)
               (input unchanged)

n = 8
A=7, D^2=149: (0,0),(1,1),(-1,0),(-4,-2),(-8,-5),(-9,-6),(-7,-5),(-4,-3)
->   d^2= 10: (3,1),(3,2),( 2,3),( 1, 3),( 0, 2),( 0, 1),( 1, 0),( 2, 0)

n = 15
A=51.5, D^2=18853: (0,0),(13,9),(36,25),(46,32),(43,30),(21,15),(2,2),(-14,-9),(-27,-18),(-50,-34),(-60,-41),(-67,-46),(-64,-44),(-45,-31),(-29,-20)
->      d^2=   82: (9,4),( 9,5),( 8, 7),( 7, 8),( 6, 8),( 3, 7),(1,6),(  0, 5),(  0,  4),(  1,  2),(  2,  1),(  4,  0),(  5,  0),(  7,  1),(  8,  2)

n = 17
A=75.5, D^2=1361: (1,-13),(1,-14),(2,-14),(3,-13),(6,-9),(8,-6),(13,2),(16,7),(20,14),(21,16),(21,17),(20,16),(17,12),(12, 5),(10, 2),(5,-6),(2,-11)
->      d^2= 137: (0,  7),(1,  5),(3,  2),(4,  1),(6, 0),(7, 0),( 9,1),(10,2),(11, 4),(11, 5),(10, 7),( 9, 8),( 7, 9),( 4,10),( 3,10),(1, 9),(0,  8)

n = 19
A=106.5, D^2=11240: (1,1),(2,2),(7,6),(11,9),(26,20),(37,28),(44,33),(61,45),(71,52),(84,61),(87,63),(86,62),(82,59),(67,48),(56,40),(38,27),(31,22),(14,10),(4,3)
->       d^2=  202: (2,3),(1,5),(0,8),( 0,9),( 1,11),( 2,12),( 3,12),( 6,11),( 8,10),(11, 8),(12, 7),(13, 5),(13, 4),(12, 2),(11, 1),( 9, 0),( 8, 0),( 5, 1),(3,2)

n = 20:
A=121: D^2=394: ( 0,0),( 1,0),( 2,1),( 2,2),( 1, 5),( 0, 7),(-2,10),(-3,11),(-6,13),(-8,14),(-11,15),(-12,15),(-13,14),(-13,13),(-12,10),(-11,8),(-9,5),(-8,4),(-5,2),(-3,1)
->     d^2=241: (13,4),(14,5),(15,7),(15,8),(14,10),(13,11),(11,12),(10,12),( 7,11),( 5,10),(  2, 8),(  1, 7),(  0, 5),(  0, 4),(  1, 2),(  2,1),( 4,0),( 5,0),( 8,1),(10,2)

n = 24:
A=260, D^2=937: ( 0, 0),( 2, 3),( 2, 4),(1, 5),(-1, 6),(-2, 6),(-5, 5),(-7, 4),(-10, 2),(-14,-1),(-15,-2),(-18,-6),(-20,-9),(-21,-11),(-22,-14),(-22,-15),(-21,-16),(-19,-17),(-18,-17),(-15,-16),(-13,-15),(-9,-12),(-8,-11),(-5,-7)
->     d^2=578: (13,17),(12,20),(11,21),(9,22),( 6,23),( 5,23),( 3,22),( 2,21),(  1,19),(  0,16),(  0,15),(  1,11),(  2, 8),(  3,  6),(  5,  3),(  6,  2),(  8,  1),( 11,  0),( 12,  0),( 14,  1),( 15,  2),(16,  5),(16,  6),(15,10)

A=238.5, D^2=657: (6,1),(5,1),(3,2),(2,3),(1, 5),(1, 6),(2,10),(3,13),(4,15),(6,18),(9,22),(10,23),(13,25),(14,25),(15,24),(16,22),(17,19),(17,17),(16,13),(15,10),(14,8),(12,5),(11,4),(8,2)
->       d^2=409: (5,2),(4,3),(2,6),(1,8),(0,11),(0,12),(1,15),(2,17),(3,18),(5,19),(8,20),( 9,20),(12,19),(13,18),(14,16),(15,13),(16, 9),(16, 7),(15, 4),(14, 2),(13,1),(11,0),(10,0),(7,1)

n = 27:
A=343.5, D^2=1233: ( 0,0),( 1,0),( 4,1),( 5,2),( 5,3),( 4,5),( 2,8),( 1,9),(-2,11),(-4,12),(-9,14),(-12,15),(-16,16),(-21,17),(-22,17),(-25,16),(-27,15),(-28,14),(-28,13),(-27,10),(-26,8),(-25,7),(-23,6),(-18,4),(-15,3),(-11,2),(-6,1)
->       d^2= 788: (18,0),(19,0),(23,1),(25,2),(26,3),(27,5),(28,8),(28,9),(27,11),(26,12),(23,14),( 21,15),( 18,16),( 14,17),( 13,17),(  9,16),(  6,15),(  4,14),(  3,13),(  1,10),(  0,8),(  0,7),(  1,6),(  4,4),  (6,3),  (9,2),(13,1)

n = 38:
A=360, D^2=71444: (1,1),(11,9),(21,19),(31,29),(41,39),(51,49),(61,59),(71,69),(81,79),(91,89),(101,99),(111,109),(121,119),(131,129),(141,139),(151,149),(161,159),(171,169),(181,179),(191,189),(181,181),(171,171),(161,161),(151,151),(141,141),(131,131),(121,121),(111,111),(101,101),(91,91),(81,81),(71,71),(61,61),(51,51),(41,41),(31,31),(21,21),(11,11)
->     d^2=32404: (0,0),( 2,0),( 2,10),( 2,20),( 2,30),( 2,40),( 2,50),( 2,60),( 2,70),( 2,80),( 2, 90),(  2,100),(  2,110),(  2,120),(  2,130),(  2,140),(  2,150),(  2,160),(  2,170),(  2,180),(  0,180),(  0,170),(  0,160),(  0,150),(  0,140),(  0,130),(  0,120),(  0,110),(  0,100),( 0,90),( 0,80),( 0,70),( 0,60),( 0,50),( 0,40),( 0,30),( 0,20),( 0,10)
```

Comment: To clarify: when you say _the largest Euclidean distance between any two points on the **circumference** of the polygon_, do you mean _on the **permiter** of the polygon_?

Comment: Yes, points on the perimeter of the polygon. See, e.g., http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2000/MS/diameter/node3.html .

Comment: I suggest removing this strict output formatting "in this format. The commas between x and y and between \$),(\$ are mandatory" as it is not core to the challenge.

Comment: Also, why are we required to output the square - that seems like unnecessary fluff.

Comment: I see that you want us to do our golf AND provide a program that wraps our golf. I don't think you should do that.

Comment: Do we have to shear the points or can we use other methods as long as the area and number of points (all integers) remain the same?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I fully understand that there are languages in which a formatted output is impossible or at least disproportionately expensive. Assembler comes to mind immediately. Of course, I don't want to exclude them from participating because of that. But if a language can easily produce formatted output, then I take the liberty of specifying a format that I can handle on trial without conversion.

Comment: @JonathanAllan  The fact that I would also like to see the squared diameter in the result is roughly equivalent to wanting to see the final amount on a restaurant bill. Although the guest can calculate it himself, he would still find a bill without the sum strange. So that's part of the job here.

Comment: @jdt Although that would of course also be very interesting, it is then a completely different and, in general, much more difficult task. This would then read something like this: only the number of vertices and the area would be given and one or more polygons with these properties would have to be determined. Specifying the polygon coordinates of the start polygon would then be superfluous. The task would be similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253633/the-smallest-area-of-a-convex-grid-polygon . So here only polygons that can be generated by shearing are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 143 bytes

```
f=\(x,`+`=\(y)max(dist(y)^2)){d=+x;for(i in 2:3)for(j in -1:1){h=0
while(+x>+{h=h-1;m=diag(2);m[i]=j*h;y=x%*%m})x=y}
`if`(d>+x,f(x),list(d,x))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVZdbhs5DH5d-GHPMAhQRGqoYqifmXHT6UViLzKN7caFnRgeF52gyBn2APvSfdhDdU-z_JGcLIokI0okP1LkRyF__X388eOfr6eN637-uekXZoLbq1tan-x-mMxqO55I_MNb-33VX03Xm8ej2Vbbh8q_D5Y3X3jj8D3a7_d9Pft2v92tzdX08Yq29w6v9_1qO3w23l7vb7bL_svb--unfnrz9s3-2U790_Psdru5NauPVxNszGRhxxFXMFn7rGn9-9vvh-P6g1uY0Q7ju_1wOm4nc1wPq3en4RMFO62nU_95_PrJXNwYWy0v4OICdG9hsTC0XxwXDxcwWgvj-tDTgbWzw-N4YtQJVv2d2W8fzHQDuLSQRb-01h6G8bSuzXA47J7MiX4m61YWEBbmWJSX5hKyeIS7x91uOIzr_hIuLf1eUsz_nc24aLvtw5rrNt4ND4bTlbQoR2uru-Fk1ju64PjBbQxdXawpF6jYAipOnNU3N365zKd2ZhDQggng6dtApC82gHzmA2DDugiez0MHvqU1BgisjxECe0Wv-zAHP-fVq71H9W8g8Y4izEwNNUeQb6LI5UTjt2Q5M043VQDHK9aAtSRaC4yavySNEOhb5-_rIGzj1M1FBXMdOM7GzcFxbq7Ne9KHF9cAcpEGPCtjky9KF6_zxcqVOAL5srnzBIYdS6kmOK6Ba0iKkkhD2igxG3KIoo2J7ETrKSGv13QYJH0CliC6hnzeaLBO88dcgwa4M55K9bryvJZzsW4BxdxDlbS0lZdOCBiHwjMlfG6JOKIUxFNBpPwt-C4zQHJCiIzXIiR26iI0DNGRN-u7Bho595AYh0oR2T8R4epXzAoIXvKL3HLCB-5JpU2ptJOVl-wqTY8O5SZkU7VSR_UkDqFWHaRq1HepDF1Qe-eoBlkIRRWyLRYQMu6ULEkxxC5p24PQlwPntKqQVxkizYvoVzWal64pn7dq5koLhEVK2JSpirnHxItCMJQOsVRooVI6a8UBiUzSeMHIUjprQ_FgszIViktGLd2qkRqnV1PmIbzcKl8qlymXLWo9yZVrNs-dpIkMmadJO6tr0jeCiKt2xMx5Xls91ylIGoP8OiVuUjpGmQH_Kz2i0kObREvQw6S96dRynqmCOvpahHnhwZkZjY6NK3PExc5CKqo2G_vCMBZCUQmNaGy67KTOAZrcnJhbEzLdfObseQrL5KHWhyeE10ivHq-JKjHXCZTJogls5HlAaHmdE4OlrjXhiMADUIvEmFp0QkWBRcJFAUZCRoHGhkdGm8PvikgdV0QkioDd-azDYtdi8ZWnQPASlhjyJEpcef4kF48lP-kLp0x_eok56qUEn-AFncAFm6AFmYAFl2AFlUAzJnda_y0o_7X8Bw)

Recursively searches for the next best shear until further reduction in diameter cannot be found. Diameter calculation function is overloaded as `+` operator. Input and output of coordinates is by `n x 2` matrix, transformation to required format is done in the footer. Note that output coordinates do not exactly match the provided test cases, but the diameters match and the shapes look the same.

Comment: Deviations in the coordinate list are OK as long as the minimum diameter is reached. The shearing sometimes has more than one result. Also happens with my PARI code.

Answer (score 2):

## PARI/GP 290 bytes

```
d(x,y)=C=0;for(i=1,#x,for(j=1,i,C=max(C,(x[i]-x[j])^2+(y[i]-y[j])^2)));C
shear(x,y)=T=D=d(x,y);until(T==D,T=D;if((t=d(x,z=y-x))<D,,if((t=d(x,z=y+x))<D));if(t<T,D=t;y=z);if((t=d(z=x-y,y))<D,,if((t=d(z=x+y,y))<D));if(t<D,D=t;x=z));for(k=1,#x,print1("("x[k]-vecmin(x)","y[k]-vecmin(y)"),"));D
```

The function \$shear(x,y)\$ has the coordinates, stored in 2 separate vectors, as arguments. Its return value is the squared diameter \$d^2\$. The transformed coordinates are written to output in the suggested format. The function \$d(x,y)\$ calculates the squared diameter.

Without any significant efforts regarding "golfing"; only to demonstrate the feasibility.

### Auxiliary functions to read input

```
readc()={my(s="");
s=strjoin(strsplit(input(),"),("),";");
s=strjoin(strsplit(s,"("),"v=[");
s=strjoin(strsplit(s,")"),"]");
eval(s)};
inpgon()={my(mxy=readc());x=mxy[,1];y=mxy[,2];d(x,y)};
```

### Example

```
inpgon()  \\ expects coordinate input from terminal delimited by "..."
"(1,1),(3,2),(6,4),(16,11),(23,16),(34,24),(38,27),(43,31),(44,32),(42,31),(39,29),(32,24),(21,16),(6,5),(2,2)"
2810  \\ returns D^2 of input

shear(x,y)  \\ call of function, prints result and returns d^2
(1,1),(3,0),(4,0),(6,1),(7,2),(8,4),(8,5),(7,7),(6,8),(4,9),(3,9),(2,8),(1,6),(0,3),(0,2),
82
```